# Running a VSTS agent with docker on ARM architecture

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I tried running a vsts build agent with [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/vsts-agent/) on a raspberry pi. There has been ARM support for this in [release 2.141](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.141.0).

When running the command

```
docker run \
-e VSTS_ACCOUNT=<name> \
-e VSTS_TOKEN=<pat> \
-it microsoft/vsts-agent
```

I get an error saying

> standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error".

Upon researching it seems that this is because of the wrong architecture. Is there a way to run or build this as ARM?

Comment: Have you logged an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues ? Usually, that gets a quick response.

Comment: Good idea, I'll make one

Comment: Yes, there's ARM support for the agent, but the docker image is still amd64.